# Custom link on home page to redirect to another object

Tags: home-page-component, custom-link

I am aware of home page component and how to create that but I have an issue that it should be org independent.

So, I have an object - Document and I created a custom link to redirect to the Document object.

This customization has been done in a sandbox so I am pretty much sure that it will not work in Production if I send it to change set.so how to make link org independent?

Comment: Can you add what you have written in your link? Are you in Classic or Lightning?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the full URL domain in your custom link embedded in Home page component in classic, Just use the relative URL. i.e **/015/o** which will land users on Documents tab.

This article will help you more on understanding how to construct effective URL:- 
[Constructing Effective Custom URL Buttons and Links](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm&type=5)